# Difficulty finding Internet passwords on keychain using terminal security command

Tags: terminal, security, password

I am trying retrieve an internet password from the keychain but I always get back:

```
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

...despite the entry being there in my key chain. The server name that I would normally place after the -s flag is long and is in the format ab-xxxx-8.somethi.abc.company.com, i.e. the server is https://ab-xxxx-8.somethi.abc.company.com

My security command is:

```
security find-internet-password -w -a my_name -r htps -s ab-xxxx-8.somethi.abc.company.com
```

I have tried all the combinations, putting it in quotes, etc. but nothing works. Any idea how I might get this password?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No. I hacked around the problem by making the password into a system password instead of an internet password, so I can access the keychain from the command line now. It would be nice to know why retrieving internet passwords doesn't work

Comment: I worked out a fix for me - the password I was trying to find was in iCloud key chain. Fixed by copying in to login key chain instead