# How can I find my saved Instagram web password in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain

Let say I've saved my Instagram password for the account "xxx". I know I could find this password using Keychain Access, but is there a way to do this in Terminal?

I've tried things like:

```
security find-internet-password -gs www.instagram.com
```

but this didn't yield the password.

Comment: The service name must match the name in the keychain, just look it up there.

Comment: @nohillside Where do I find the service name? I only see Kind, Account, Where and Modified.

Comment: The column is called "Name". If you select an entry, it's the bold title at the top of the Keychain Access window.

Comment: @nohillside I tried it with what it says: security find-internet-password -gs "www.instagram.com (xxx)"

Comment: What result do you get? Does it work with other accounts/entries? What is the result of `security dump-keychain|grep -i instagram`?

Comment: @nohillside It says nothing was found in the keychain, even though I've checked and it's there in Keychain Access.

Comment: And if you run `security dump-keychain|grep -i instag`?

Comment: @nohillside I did that and then ran it and still: "SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain."

Comment: You shouldn't get this error when running `security dump-keychain|grep -i instag`, even if there is no entry matching `instag`?!

Comment: @nohillside I ran exactly that followed by the updated code (security find...). Still same not found result.

Comment: Is the password in the iCloud keychain, instead of the login keychain? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271657/difficulty-finding-internet-passwords-on-keychain-using-terminal-security-comman

Comment: @Redarm yes it is iCloud

Comment: @natojato that‘s not what I proposed :-)

Comment: @natojato As far as I can see iCloud keychain does not get searched.`security list-keychains` only lists the login and System keychains here.

Answer (score 2):

The name you need to pass to `security find-internet-password` is the name shown in Keychain Access, either from the Name column of the entry or the title shown at the top of the Keychain Access window when the entry is selected.

You can also search through the keychain directly by running

```
security dump-keychain | grep -i instagram
```

PS: In my case the result was

```
$ security dump-keychain | grep -i instagram
    0x00000007 <blob>=0xx...xxx  "instagram.com (Passwords\302\240not\302\240saved)"
    "srvr"<blob>="instagram.com"
```

with some Unicode characters mingled into the Name field (which explains why `find-internet-password` wasn't able to find a match).

Comment: I did exactly this. I still don't get any result.  Again, I've checked Keychain Access and it's there. The name is "www.instagram.com (xxx)", the kind is "Web form password", the keychain label is "iCloud", the account is "xxx" and the where label is "https://www.instagram.com".

Comment: On a side note, would it be possible to copy the iCloud keychain to the Local one?